# Ignition-Physics: Bullet physics engine support?

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

On the [Ignition Robotics Roadmap](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/all/roadmap#planned-features) it is mentioned that support for Bullet (Physics Engine) is planned. Is there a timeline for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24453/ignition-physics:-bullet-physics-engine-support?/) by [Jaldert](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/22940/jaldert/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

There isn't a fixed timeline yet. We did a good push a while back but now that's on hold given other priorities. You can find the current progress on the following pull requests. If I recall correctly, the main missing piece is mesh support.

- https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-physics/pull-requests/99/
- https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/pull-requests/421/

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2020-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0